# Использование русских букв

Tags: wordpress

Как установить русский язык для интерфейса создания базы данных?

Изучаю уроки для работы с wordpress.
В одном из уроков, программа по созданию базы данных, но на русском, а у меня на английском. Как сделать на русском?

Может, в каком-то надо что-то изменить или где-то файл какой-то заменить?

P.S. Скачивал русскую версию.
На сайте написано:

> "Текущая версия русского дистрибутива всегда доступна по этой прямой ссылке.
>
> Это оригинальный дистрибутив, собранный вместе с пакетом локализации. Также переведены файлы установки, не использующие механизм интернационализации:
>
> readme.html
>
> wp-config-sample.php
>
> wp-admin/setup-config.php
>
> Отличия касаются только текста выводимых сообщений. Никаких функциональных изменений не произведено. Пакет локализации находится в каталоге wp-content/languages."

Не могу понять, что делать с этим пакетом в `wp-content/languages`?

Comment: Для начала установить вам движок, а потом в панели управления выбрать русскую локализацию.

Answer (score 1):

Скачайте не с оф. сайта, а с РУнета уже готовую версию русскую локализацию.

Насчет PMA

Заходите на localhost/denwer/
там внизу будет ссылка "Заведение новой БД и пользователя"
Пароль администратора БД, оставите пустым, остальное заполняете, потом при установке ВП вбиваете 
Хост db: localhost,
имя юзера бд,
саму бд,
пароль бд,

и ВП считайте установлена!